# What do auto-implemented properties on a list do and how do they work?

Tags: c#

I understand the concept of auto-implemented properties when it comes to object properties but I ran into them when they are applied to a list and I'm not really sure what is going on. They either get the entire list or individual objects of the list but im not really sure. It looks something like this:

```
public Ilist<myClass> className {get;set;}
```

Comment: There is no difference between a list and any other object.  What don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having trouble with understanding automated properties you can always expand it to the one with backing field and check how it looks like.

```
public Ilist<myClass> className {get;set;}
```

is equivalent

```
private IList<myClass> _className;
public Ilist<myClass> className
{
    get { return _className; }
    set { _className = value; }
}
```

As you can see, there is just one field for `IList<myClass>` instance. So you can store **one** `IList<myClass>` instance in the property. And that's what you `get`/`set` using the property: the entire list.

But because list is a collection, it can itself contain multiple `myClass` instances. So you can get it from property and then enumerate, add new items to it, etc.

Answer (score 2):

They're no different from any other property. It refers to the list as an object, not individual list elements. So, if you were to use the setter, you would be assigning a value to the list itself (i.e. reassigning the list to point to a different list) rather than setting an element.

Answer (score 1):

Auto properties don't have any special behavior for container types. Your auto property is equivalent to the following code:

```
public IList<myClass> className
{
    get
    {
        return classNamek__BackingField;
    }
    set
    {
        classNamek__BackingField = value;
    }
}

// generated by compiler; its name is really "<className>k__BackingField"
private IList<myClass> className__BackingField;
```

So the property is a list object. The getter returns the entire list object, and the setter sets the list object to a specified list object.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing `className` it will return the complete list of `myClass` objects as a List.  You can enumerate or access each `myClass` object using the List properties/methods.